# FIRST() function: Unrecognized is not currently supported as an analytic function

Tags: google-bigquery

When I run the  `aerobic-forge-504:job_4_p6sq__0C5_3B-NVyVgg-Y2gf4` job, I got a pretty weird error message

```
SELECT  fullVisitorId as fullvisitorid,
        date,
        (visitStartTime+hits.time) as time,
        first(customDimensions.value) over(partition by fullVisitorId)
        FROM flatten([google.com:analytics-bigquery:LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910] ,customDimensions)
where customDimensions.index=2
LIMIT 100
```

Error: Unrecognized is not currently supported as an analytic function. Not sure what is wrong here.

I want to return the first `customDimemsion` value for index=2 together with the date it was first recorded. Since `customDimension` and `hits` are both repeated fields, and somehow separated not sure if this is even possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper name for the analytic function in SQL Standard is FIRST_VALUE. FIRST is aggregation function in BigQuery. So your query will be

```
SELECT  fullVisitorId as fullvisitorid,
        date,
        (visitStartTime+hits.time) as time,
        first_value(customDimensions.value) over(partition by fullVisitorId)
        FROM flatten([google.com:analytics-bigquery:LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910] ,customDimensions)
where customDimensions.index=2
LIMIT 100
```

**Update** To answer the question

> I want to return the first customDimemsion value for index=2 together
>   with the date it was first recorded.

I would try to use hits.customDimensions.[index|value], i.e.

```
SELECT fullVisitorId, date, visitStartTime + first_hit_time, value FROM (
SELECT  fullVisitorId,
        date,
        visitStartTime,
        FIRST(hits.customDimensions.value) WITHIN hits as value,
        FIRST(hits.time) WITHIN hits as first_hit_time
FROM
[google.com:analytics-bigquery:LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910]
WHERE hits.customDimensions.index = 2)
```

Comment: Do you happen to know how to rewrite this as `FLATTEN` doesn't work with `TABLE_DATE_RANGE` and we actually query for multiple days.

Comment: FLATTEN not working with TABLE_DATE_RANGE is an annoyance, but I think it can be workarounded by using FLATTEN(SELECT * FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE(...), ...) instead. P.S. I think that use of FLATTEN is almost always a mistake, so if you can tell the actual task you are doing, maybe there is a way to do it without FLATTEN.

Comment: task is the last phrase from the question, eventually I want to get back a list of fullvisitorid, and for each unique fullvisitorid only one row with the first customdimension value, and time when that was set. Let me know if it's not clear.

Comment: Just to clarify - the "date it was first recorded" wouldn't it simply be visitStartTime, since first hits.time is always 0 ?

Comment: Our index=2 customDimension is a search term the user enters, it's not the first interaction of the user on the website, so it's not hits.time=0, it can be the fifth or even later interaction with the website. It might be request number 30 something. Does this help? It can be even days later after he came to the website and did his first search. We want to use this info, in order to compute the time elapsed between using the search and actual purchase

Comment: I updated the answer with one idea how to filter hits on customDimensions.index